# Populate tree view without values from XML document in C#

Tags: c#, xml, treeview

Using Visual C# in Visual Studio 2010 I followed the following example to add the nodes of an XML document to a tree view.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317597/en-us

So far this works fine. However the given piece of code in #7 displays all nodes including the values, e.g. when reaching `<myNode>2</myNode>` the value `2` is also displayed.

How can I change the example so that only all node names excluding their value will be populated to the tree view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the piece of code that goes:

```
if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
{
    // child nodes
    for (...)
    {
        xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
        inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));  // here the leafs are created
        tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[i];
        AddNode(xNode, tNode);
    }
}
else
{
    // it's a leaf
    inTreeNode.Text = ...  // here it is set
}
```

For your requirement you ought to restructure the whole recursive method but a simple fix is to move the HasChildNodes up:

```
if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
{
    // child nodes
    for (...)
    {
        xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];

        if (! xNode.HasChildNodes) // a leaf?
           continue;  // then skip 

        inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));  // here the leafs are created
        tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[i];
        AddNode(xNode, tNode);
    }
}
else
{
    // it's a leaf, should only happen for the root now
    inTreeNode.Text = ...  // here it is set
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine! I just stick with your solution without restructuring the method :-)